# How to get default metrics of flux using micrometer?

Tags: project-reactor, micrometer

Is it possible to collect flux metrics of project-reactor using LoggingMeterRegistry in micrometer?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible by simply adding the `LoggingMeterRegistry` to the global Micrometer registry, then calling `.metrics()` on the `Flux`/`Mono` at the point you wish to instrument. You can think of it as instrumenting the signals of the operator above `metrics()`, the same way `.log()` logs signals of the portion of the sequence above it.